# IOS firebase connection stuck on 'Run your app to verify installation'

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a Flutter application on both iOS and Android, for this I need to use notifications and I made it work on android successfully after some hard part ( flutter clean FTW ).

I now wanted to do the same for iOS and I have problems connecting the app to the firebase backend, I followed step by step the [Tutorial on the firebase_messaging pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) but I can't get it to connect on the 5th and last task on the the firebase backend. It's stuck on 'Run your app to verify installation, you might need to uninstall and reinstall it again'.

Of course I downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist and put it next to info.plist and I've added the FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled key as well as this code in the AppDelegate :

```swift
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
```

I also made sure to activate the push notifications and background modes capabilities on Xcode.

But somehow it still doesn't work at all and stuck on the same message, yet I can use the firebase tool to get the user Token for example ?!?!

I also made the call so that the user enable the app to get notifications.

Here's my flutter doctor :

[image]

Can anyone help me with this? I found a lot of issues on GitHub for this but no clear answer have been given yet. I don't have any error message or really anything more that could help identify what's wrong there.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Sadly i can't really run on an emulator because the mac i have is so slow that the emulator make it unusable... And i can't put 1000€ on a new one for this. Yes it doesn't stop the app from working but it does not receive the notifications which is central for my app. Why is this so hard, it's a core feature for flutter, what app doesn't have notifications?

Comment: Yes i do all my tests on that

Comment: Thanks for the recommandation, that's what made it work for android for me but saddly it does not for ios :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of time i finnaly did get notifications on my IOs device, since i had the firebase Token of the Iphone, i managed to send a notification to this deveice even thought it still isn't connected to the firebase backend.